# answer.ros.org askbot inbox icon is red when inbox is empty

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The envelope icon next to the username on the askbot site is stuck red.  I cleared my inbox (dismissed all notifications) but the icon is still red (it used to be white).

**Update**: This is a bug. A bug has been filed [upstream](http://askbot.org/en/question/371/why-is-my-inbox-icon-still-red-even-when-my-inbox). A fix was checked into askbot April 25th to prevent further occurances. However to fix stale inbox counts on the current install the following command must be run:

```
python manage.py fix_inbox_counts
```

Can some admin please run this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9733/answer.ros.org-askbot-inbox-icon-is-red-when-inbox-is-empty/) by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1607 on 2011-04-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-20**:
This is happening to my account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After testing it seems that it will remain red until you dismiss the notifications.  You can talk to [upstream](http://askbot.org) about whether that's the correct behavior.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-15**:
I've recently started experiencing this bug (even with all notifications dismissed) - was the patch mentioned in the update to the question ever applied to the AskBot running ROS Answers?

**Comment by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on 2011-11-25**:
Red Envelope for me too :( Can someone reset this? Thanks!

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-01**:
I have also met this problem now.What can I do? Thank you~

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2011-04-25**:
added to upstream: http://askbot.org/en/question/371/why-is-my-inbox-icon-still-red-even-when-my-inbox